# How to remove elements once it was created by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JQuery, I was wondering why my script is not working. I have been reading through the API and I did exactly what it says but I am still not getting what I was expecting. Please find the script below:

```
//To infinitely add images
$('.add_upload_image').on('click', function(){
    $('.upload_image').append('<input type="file" name="userfile[]"/><br/>');
});

//To remove the last child of the .upload_image
$('.remove_upload_image').on('click', function(){
    $('.upload_image input:last-child').remove();   
});
```

So I am sure you understand what I am trying to achieve. But basically, i have a text that says 'click to add more uploads' which is wrapped around with the `.add_upload_image` then when the user clicks on it, it adds the input element to the div class `.upload_image`. Works fine. However, when the user clicks on the 'click to remove' which is wrapped in `.remove_upload_image` and I am aiming at the last child of the `.upload_image` that is input and it is not removing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Sure I will get to that asap

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DRA2U/

Comment: `:last-child` isn't what you're thinking of. Try using `.last()`: `$('.upload_image input').last().remove()`. The reason it's not working is because you also append a `<br />`, making the `input` element **not** a "last-child". Note that it'll leave the `<br />`. You might want to wrap those both in a different element that gets appended, and target the last of those. Read the explanation of `:last-child`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Comment: Please find the jsfiddle above

Comment: Might want to get rid of the `br` tags too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `:last`, not `:last-child` ( the `<br>` element is the last child ):

```
$('.remove_upload_image').on('click', function(){
    $('.upload_image input:last').remove();   
});
```

You should probably remove the `<br>` element as well:

```
$('.remove_upload_image').on('click', function(){
    var el = $('.upload_image input:last');
    el.add(el.next('br')).remove();   
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2fNwR/2/)

Comment: Thank you - I guess there are different ways to do this. I will explore around with jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.upload_image').last().remove()
```

This should work.